# Android: How to add a vertical progress bar to a home screen widget?

Tags: android, widget, progress-bar

I need to put a vertical scroll bar in a home screen widget, and after searching many times, I can't find a convenient solution that works on API3 and above!

I tried many solutions:
- using bitmap created at run-time, but on some displays it never reach 100%
- a patch9 bitmap, but the scroll bar display gets completely messed up when the progress is near 0.
- using the addView() with 100 existing layout and it works great, except it's only available since API7!
- including all 100 layouts and showing only one at a time, work fine, but what a mess to include those in my 8 different widget layouts!

I tried to use the weight programmatically but it's not possible either, any other solution to resize a view based on a %?

Here is one progress bar layout I currently use:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_weight="11" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/scale"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="89" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I found so far is to have all the possible progress levels ready to use in various Xml layout files.

On Android API < 7, all those need to be included in a single xml layout and shown/hidden at run-time, while on Android API >= 7, one can actually use addRemoteView() to include the desired layout in a much more efficient way!

Answer (score -1):

You should use [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)! You must place this within a layout. By default, scrollview is for Vertical Scroll. If you want horizontal scroll you must specify HorizontalScrollView. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not looking for a scrollview, but a vertical progress bar that I can set at run-time to represent the battery level (or other data). For now I'm using 100 layout files as the above one to match a progress bar from 0% to 100%. Very heavy, at least it works, but can't change the color.